# Podcast Cover Art Help!

Tags: raw, jpeg, photography-basics, art, pixels

My Photographer Shot in Raw with 885 × 1024 dimensions. I need this for a podcast cover at 1,400 x 1400 pixels -3,000 x 3000. Please help?

Comment: What do you want help with, exactly? Why not ask the photographer for a larger image?

Comment: I don't think he has one. He sent the .jpg to me. The dimensions are 885 × 1024. He's kind of a new photographer but shot on a real expensive Canon camera. He said he shot in RAW. He doesn't think he has a larger image. Do you think he does?

Comment: Yes. Every Canon camera produced in the last ~20 years produces images much larger than 885×1024. The problem is probably either: the image needed to be cropped to make the subject fill the frame and this is all that's left, or simply that he isn't familiar with the options in exporting from his RAW conversion software.

Comment: But it's really hard to guess without a lot more detail of his process.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking to! Ok thanks so much. Yes the photo needed to be cropped a bit. Maybe if I get the original I can get someone to crop it?

Comment: He sent me the original and its smaller than the first 1024 × 682. Do you think he had a setting turned on his camera that made this happen? Anything I can ask him to do?

Comment: Depens on the camera model, but for example the 40D (c 2007) had a smallest JPG setting of  1936 x 1288 pixels. IMO 1024 x 682 seems awfully small for any file straight out of the camera

Comment: it looks like he doesn't earn the title 'photographer'. You have to actively mess things up to get to such a small resolution, being clueless is not enough.

Comment: Aditionally... you do not *need* a podcast cover of 1400x1400. Yes a retina display could ask for more, but my humble 24 inch HD monitor looks terrific with just 1080px height.

Comment: A raw image would be at least 3000x2000 pixels, probably more.  1024x885 is not raw.

Comment: If he shot to raw, the camera generated crw or cr2 file. Ask for that instead of the jpg

Answer (score 3):

885x1024 sounds like your contact emailed the image to you and his email software/system has resized the image.

Ask them to zip the image file and send it again, or use an online service like dropbox or OneDrive.

Comment: Oh, good call. Seems likely to be right.

Answer (score 1):

You could resample the photo to the larger size(s) in Photoshop, but the lost detail would not be recovered and it would just look like a slightly blurred image.

You need to ask the photographer for the images in higher resolution - either ask him or her to create those specific resolutions for you, or just to give you the original source resolution and let you do the resampling yourself.